# Alt key behaviour with Javascript on Chrome/Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, keyup

I'm trying to emulate a behaviour of a windows menu where you could navigate menus using an combination like: `alt + KEY + KEY ...` as a simple test I did this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  $(".dropdown>a").css("text-decoration","underline");
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
        $(".dropdown>a").css("text-decoration","")
});
```

Which should add or remove an underline for all my links under .dropdown whenever I press any key on the website, it works fine for all , but the Alt key, with this key the system appears to be awaiting another key to be pressed and will only show the underline if I press alt twice.

I'm wondering if this is something that can be worked around or is something regarding the operating system. Why does is happen?

Comment: it can be related to how your browser handles the alt key, might be it activates its own menus. Your code works fine for all keys including alt on my ubuntu+chrome

Comment: added windows to the description, @CrowbarKZ interesting, maybe this is hardware related then?

Comment: I think its more browser-related. You can also check if e.preventDefault() solves your problem.

Comment: @CrowbarKZ aparently that solved the issue, please write that as an answer... now I'll take a look at chrome's bugtracker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be related to how your browser handles the alt key, might be it activates its own menus. Your code works fine for all keys including alt on my ubuntu+chrome.

You can also check if `e.preventDefault()` solves your problem.